# Symfony2 modify global user reference?

Tags: php, symfony

I have functions setAttribute($key, $value) and getAttribute($key, $default) in my User class. When the user is authenticated I want to set several attributes to be set that will be used later in various controllers.

I tried setting the attributes in my success handler function:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
      $token->getUser()->setAttribute("user_data_set", 1);
 }
```

But when I tried calling it in my controller the value has not been set

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    //Get the logged in user
    $user = $this->getUser(); 
    //Entity Manager
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // this page is just used as the starting point to redirect the user to the appropriate page
    if($user->getAttribute("user_data_set", 0) == 1)
    {
        //Get Symfony1 route from the user data table
        $old_homepage = $user->getAttribute("user_homepage", "@default_homepage");
        //Convert route to Symfony2 format
        $new_homepage = $this->setForwardingAddress($old_homepage);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($new_homepage));
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->redirect('login');
    }        


}
```

How can I modify the global user instead of a local reference?

Comment: if you don't want to persist it on the DB, why aren't you using the session to store the attributes?

Comment: @lsouza I'm dealing with a lot of legacy code. I'm upgrading our site from Symfony 1.4 to 2.5. The legacy code has a built in getAttribute/setAttribute functions in the User class. The legacy code has an extended User class that sets user attributes and makes database requests. I tried to emulate that by creating a User repository. Would it be a bad idea to set session variables from within a repository?

Comment: Instead of the repository you could create a UserManager service, and deal with everything you need there, from session jandling to User operations. A repository is very usefull, but should deal only with the database.

Comment: @Isouza I implemented a User Manager as you suggested. I set it as a service and injected a container to retrieve the session/security.context and entity manager for database calls. Would it be better for me to separate the database calls into the User repository? It seems unnecessary since all of the functions would be used exclusively by this service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously want cross-request solution so you'll need to use `DB` or `session`.

For example:

```
// Injecting Session service
public function __construct(Session $session){
    $this->session = $session
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $this->session->set('user_data_set', 1);
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
$foo = $session->get('user_data_set');
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the solution I went with. This is essentially what my legacy code was doing anyway.